# Laravel: Query childless elements in a table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this simple table containing all categories:

Category:
id|name|parentid

Using Eloquent, how can I query all the categories that have no childs?

Comment: what are childs?, explain further with your code

Comment: With childs I mean:

Categories which value for 'id' does not occur as a value of 'parentid' for other categories.

Answer (score 1):

you have to build a relation and then you can use the following

```
$query = Category::query();
$query->whereDoesntHave('child');
$query->get();
```

or simplest is

```
Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

but it might be better setting up a 'children' relationship in the model and doing it using that:

**Category.php**

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

**Usage**

```
Category::whereDoesntHave('children')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I had to change this though:

return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'id', 'parentid);

to

return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parentid', 'id');

Comment: ah, I will update the answer, I always get those the wrong way around.